# Android studio plugin : Adding icon near SDK manager

Tags: android, plugins, intellij-idea, android-studio

I am trying to create a plugin for android studio, and I want to add my plugin near android studio's SDK Manager with Icon.

I am able to add the same in top navigation bar options. But not able to add plugin as icon near SDK manager.

Does anyone know how to do it? which group id should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. In your plugins.xml file, just add

```
<action id="mainActionId" class="actions.MyClassName" text="Plugin" description="My Plugin">
      <add-to-group group-id="MainToolBar" anchor="last"/>
      <keyboard-shortcut keymap="$default" first-keystroke="shift meta D"/>
</action>
```

This will add your plugin at the end of the main tool bar. 
If you want to give an icon for the same, then add icon attribute in action tag.